# How to automate a models update of my project from my database in a Azure DevOps continuous deployment?

Tags: database, asp.net-web-api, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a project that uses Entity Framework with **Database First** approach. Everytime I have an update in the database, I need to manually **update the model** of my project in the Visual Studio. Like in the image:
[link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zGJ2.png)

But that became an issue when the process is **authomatized** in a deploy process of my aplication. In the deploy process, there is an change in the database of QA to Prod.

**How can I include in the steps of my continuous deployment an update to de models from the data base?**

Answer (score 1):

> How can I include in the steps of my continuous deployment an update
> to de models from the data base?

If your project targets asp.net core, you can use command-line tool to update your database via [command-line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) task.

Check [Entity Framework Core tools reference - .NET Core CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)：

They create migrations, apply migrations, and generate code for a model based on an existing database.